# BrowserField2 - salesforce oauth2 failing at Accept/Deny stage

Tags: oauth, salesforce, browserfield

I have a BlackBerry java-based app that works with salesforce data and uses oauth 2 for authentication. It has been working fine until recently when users have been complaining that once they get to the accept/deny salesforce oauth page, clicking on Accept button displays a salesforce 404 page.

I attached a debugger to the bb simulator (OS7) and found that everything was working fine up to the point where a POST is made to salesforce on pressing the ACCEPT button in the final stage of authentication/authorisation via salesforce oauth2 user agent flow. At this point, the post would succeed and the response body would contain some markup with a small JavaScript block that just performs a document.location.href assignment to force the browser to navigate to a new URL. I noticed that the URL was not what I was expecting - I was expecting to see the redirect_uri callback address + the access token etc data appended to the end of it (as per the sf oauth2 documentation). What I saw instead was a URL that when navigated to leads the user back to a login page with a message saying that they are attempting to access a resource that requires authentication.

If I perform the same flow in say chrome the URL after the post is what I expect. This all used to work just fine so I am confused as to why it would stop working all of a sudden. I've heard that Salesforce changed their oauth 2 implementation back in late 2011 slightly so I wonder if this has broken my client although I don't see how.

As an experiment I removed all of my code except for an embedded BrowserField and made it navigate to the oauth URL as constructed by combining consumer key and various other values as per the documentation and it still fails with a 404 page at the point of clicking on the accept button after a successful login.

If I try the same bootstrap oauth URL in the built in bb browser the full authentication flow works fine and I am eventually redirected to the final callback URL with access token information appended.

Has anyone else out there had trouble with oauth2 user agent flow on BrowserField (from field2 package)?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the "scope=mobile" parameter?   This parameter puts you into a very simplified oauth flow that is optimized for blackberry...we've found they generally have trouble getting through the richer flows designed for iOS/Android.   That said, I haven't heard of them having issues on BB7...only the 5 and sometimes 6 series

If that fails, could you open a support case with us?

Answer (score 1):

Try also "`display=mobile`" and "`scope=api web`" (with a space), depending on what you are trying to access after OAuth.